# setting $JAVA_HOME and installing JDK

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I'm trying to install maven on my macbook OS X 10.10. It looked a bit complicated so I've find this step by step tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghIvOYDs0BM) which looked very easy. The only problem was that:

> echo $JAVA_HOME

didn't show anything although I do have JDK installed.

> java -version

returns

> java version "1.8.0_25"

I tried to set $JAVA_HOME manually but it didn't helped. So I went to the /usr/ or usr/lib/ where java should be located, nothing's here and spotlight even doesn't find "JVM"

Can anyone help me how to set $JAVA_HOME correctly? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set JAVA_HOME=your directory\jdk1.8.0_25;
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```